# What happens behind the scenes when a JNLP file is launched?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to debug an issue with outdated JNLP resources and would like to better understand how they actually work.

I am using a JNLP file to run an application from a remote server. In my testing, I managed to create a copy JNLP, like the one below, that would instead pull the resources from my local machine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:/C:/local/path/to/my/jnlp" href="Client.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Client</title>
        <description>Development Testing</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <property name="jnlp.env" value="dev"/>   
        <jar href="lib/client.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/Utils-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="path.to.main.client.Class" />
</jnlp>
```

I was running this in Eclipse, and everything seemed to work as expected. I then copied the JNLP file out of Eclipse into a different directory on my computer, ran the file, and it again worked as expected.

I then changed the saved file to the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:/C:/local/path/to/my/jnlp" href="Client.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Client</title>
        <description>Development Testing</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <property name="jnlp.env" value="dev"/>   
        <jar href="lib/client.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/Utils-1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="path.to.main.client.Class" />
</jnlp>
```

When I reran the JNLP copied outside of Eclipse, it gave me an error saying it could not find the Utils-1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file. Upon inspecting the JNLP in Notepad++, however, I saw that the `<resource>` entry was still Utils-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar.

This eventually led me to two questions:

1. When a JNLP file is downloaded and double-clicked, which file determines where to look for resources (or which to look for): the local copy or the remote copy defined in the file? I'm a bit confused as to why the JNLP I run lists one jar version in it, but the jar that is searched for is different. Other times I've run the same file, and it seems to be fine looking for 1.3.6. I think there's some part that I'm missing.
2. Are these files and the dependencies cached somewhere where I can actually view them? I've read that `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\` should have these files, but the only things I see there are two directories called "security" and "6.0". The "6.0" folder has files and folders that appear to be updated when a JNLP is run, but they are simply another set of mysterious folders numbered 0-63 all containing files with hexadecimal strings for names.

I appreciate any insight into the inner workings of these things.

Comment: `javaws -viewer` will show you your cached applications.  `javaws -clearcache` will clear them.  I am certain the location of the cached files, by platform, is *somewhere* on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: For general errors you may also try JaNeLa - its a JNLP analyzer... (https://github.com/AlBundy33/JaNeLa)

Comment: @Lonzak A built Jar of JaNeLA is also available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ah ok I search for it but didn't found anything. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Lonzak *"I search for it but didn't found anything."* Yeah, I guess some little app. I shoved on my share drive would not rank high in the 'search' scheme of things. *"Thanks for the link!"* You're welcome. :)

Comment: Yes if you would put it up on e.g. github it would certainly rank higher...